# how to create scale with n numeric values in R

Tags: r

for example I have in a variable the different ages of people:

```r
ed <- c(51,51,44,25,49,52,21,45,29,46,34,33,30,28,50,21,25,21,22,51,25,52,39,53,52,23,20,23,34)
```

but it turns out I want to summarize this huge **amount in seven rows**

```r
---------------
scale     | h
---------------
20 - 25   |  9
26 - 30   |  3
31 - 35   |  3
36 - 40   |  1
41 - 45   |  2
46 - 50   |  3
51 - 55   |  7
```

**Are there any libraries that allow to create scales?**

I have tried it with conditionals and it is very tedious

Comment: `table(cut(ed, seq(0,55,by=5)))`

Comment: excellent your comment @r2evans